# SelectorGadget selecting non visible elements

Tags: r, web-scraping, selector, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data from the following site [wikipedia Athens](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1).

I am using SelectorGadget in order to select the elements that I'm interested in. One of the elements that I am supposed to fetch is the official webpage of the city of Athens (   http://www.cityofathens.gr/), which is located to the right and below the small maps.
 When I am clicking on the element to find some proper selector, the GadgetSelector proposes the selector ".free", which is actually selecting 12 links, although only the one I am interested in is flagged green. So I can't see any other links inside the page to unselect them, however they are selected by themselves. Can anyone suggest a way to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in that particular link and need not to generalize, we can use:

```
library(rvest)
# This is the url you provided
url <- 'https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1'
a <- read_html(url) %>% 
    # This select only the first node
    html_node('.free') %>% 
    # Extract the link
    html_attr('href')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am sorry because, as a matter of fact, the link is one of the elements that I'm interested in retrieving (with city name, population etc being some others) and it's something that I have to do for several pages/cities. However, this particular problem only came up with this particular page... all the other elements  for al the other pages are retrieved almost perfect!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve then? Which are the other pages? what is different about this one?

Comment: I have to retrieve data(city name, population, area, website)  from Wikipedia for some other cities of Greece, as well. However, in all other cities, only one link is selected, I don't know why this is happening with this particular page...

Comment: The infobox on Athen's page is indeed different from that of others cities (e.g.: https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3%CF%80%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B7) What I think should work is to harvest the whole infobox, and then filter/manipulate the result as a data.frame in R. `read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes('.infobox') %>% 
    html_table(fill =T)`

Comment: I will give it a try. So far, what I did is to just retrieve all the data I needed (plus the extra links) and then remove them.